# Unknown provider in angular unit testing

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller:

```
angular.module("controllers").controller("AddController", function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $timeout, $routeParams, Todos, MessageQueue) {
   // ... code
});
```

and this test:

```
describe("AddController", function() {

   var ctrl;
   var scope;

   beforeEach(module('controllers'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('AddController', {
         $scope: scope
      });
   }));

   it("should be available", function() {
      expect(ctrl).not.toBe(undefined);
   });

});
```

Karma says:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27-build.533+sha.c8c2386/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams
```

But in my karma.config I am importing `bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js`. Here:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
   config.set({
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      files: [
         'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
         'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
         'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

         'app/scripts/app.js',
         'app/scripts/services/mod.js',
         'app/scripts/directives/mod.js',
         'app/scripts/controllers/mod.js',

         'app/scripts/**/*.js',
         'test/spec/**/*Spec.js'
      ],
      exclude: [
      ],
      preprocessors: {
      },
      reporters: ['progress'],
      port: 9876,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      autoWatch: true,
      browsers: ['Firefox'],
      singleRun: false
   });
};
```

I am a bit puzzled. Anyone?

Comment: is your controller running well outside test ? 
You should inject $routeParams in your controller.

Comment: @Absor I edited the question with the whole karma.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the '$routeParams' object yourself to the `$controller` call, it would look like this then:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('AddController', {
         $scope: scope,
         $routeParams: {id: '...'}
      });
   }));
```

Comment: It works! But why does it not do it by itself? Isn't Karma supposed to  resolve all the dependencies when unit testing too?

Comment: It isn't Karma. Angular itself doesn't provide any mock for $routeParams as it probably doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant angular. So what is it the rule? Of that controller signature, what can I rely on? What will be provided?